# run a URL from its own server

Tags: php, linux, bash, http, wget

I have dynamic pages set up `http://something.comm/dynamic/fake/folder`. This really runs a single php file that reads the request_uri to determine what to load (dynamically).

I am currently running a loop that does `wget --spider $url` in order to ping each page.

If it wasn't a dynamic URL and was a script, I'd be able to just run `php /path/to/real/file.php`, but since they are generated dynamically I can only access the script by pinging a specific url.

So is it possible to simulate an http request to the same server, or a better way I can ping these "virtual urls" without a real http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a PHP CGI binary, you can set the `PATH_INFO` environment variable and run the PHP script with `php-cgi`, e.g.:

```
PATH_INFO=/dynamic/fake/folder php-cgi /path/to/real/file.php
```

If you have a query string (that is, a `?` plus some more stuff), put that in the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable, too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I understand it yet, but initial tests look good. I'll know for sure tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: This looks good, only issue I see is that it is not recognizing `$_GET` query strings on the fake folder

Comment: @d-_-b: Try sticking the query string into the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable.

Comment: Aweomse, thanks so much for your help with this! I never knew I could do this.